# Reactive.NET Conditional Throttle

Tags: c#, system.reactive

Is there a way to have conditional throttle.

I have a class which has an event with 2 parameters (control sender, string text).I would like to use this event in my Rx code, and use throttling. The only problem is that i would like to throttle text, only for the same sender.

So if the sender = textbox1, then throttle for 300 seconds, however if the sender changes then ignore throttle and send the event up in the chain.

`sender=textbox1, text = 'm' within 300 seconds (ignore)` 
`sender textbox1, text = 'mu' within 300 seconds (ignore)` 
`sender textbox1, text = 'muk' more than 300 seconds (process)`

`sender=textbox1, text = 'm' within 300 seconds(ignore)` 
`sender=textbox2, text = 'y' within 300 seconds(process) //as the sender has changed now.`

Comment: Which event do you want to send up the chain?  It seems like you'd want to send "textbox1", "m" up the chain since now you have an event from textbox2.  But you would not want to send textbox2 up the chain unless 300s goes by otherwise you would not be throttling lots of textbox2 events?  Is that what you mean?

Comment: Why not throttle and buffer them separately, then merge the results as they come in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will make sure that 300ms have passed before showing a value, unless the sender has changed.

```
var source = new Subject<Pair>();

// The Publish().RefCount() and Subscribe() are to make the sequence hot
var changedSender = source.DistinctUntilChanged(p => p.Sender).Publish().RefCount();
changedSender.Subscribe();

var throttled = source.Select(p =>
    Observable.Amb(changedSender, source.Skip(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300))).Take(1))
    .Concat();

throttled.Subscribe(WritePair);

source.OnNext(new Pair("A", "i"));
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
source.OnNext(new Pair("A", "it"));
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
source.OnNext(new Pair("A", "bit"));
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
source.OnNext(new Pair("A", "bite"));
source.OnNext(new Pair("B", "a"));
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
source.OnNext(new Pair("A", "bitey"));
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
source.OnNext(new Pair("A", "at"));
```

This produces the following output:

```
A: bite
B: a
A: bitey
A: at
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Although i realised i want something a little bit different that the output. What i want is that is show A: bite before B:a. I want the previous value before the change. i made the some changes to your code to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i have done to make this work

```
        var source = new Subject<Pair>();


        // The Publish().RefCount() and Subscribe() are to make the sequence hot
        //var changedSender = source.DistinctUntilChanged(p => p.Sender).Publish().RefCount();
        var changedSender = source.Zip(source.Skip(1), (previous, next) => new { Previous = previous, Next = next }).DistinctUntilChanged(arg => arg.Next.Sender).Select(o => o.Previous).Publish().RefCount();
        changedSender.Subscribe();
        var either = changedSender.Merge(source.Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300))); //.Do(o => Console.WriteLine("Do {0}", o.ToString()));
        either.Subscribe(o => o.Print());


        source.OnNext(new Pair("A", "i"));
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
        source.OnNext(new Pair("A", "it"));
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
        source.OnNext(new Pair("A", "bit"));
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
        source.OnNext(new Pair("A", "bite"));
        source.OnNext(new Pair("A", "bite1"));
        source.OnNext(new Pair("A", "bite2"));
        source.OnNext(new Pair("B", "a"));
        source.OnNext(new Pair("B", "ani"));
        source.OnNext(new Pair("B", "animal"));
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
        source.OnNext(new Pair("A", "bitey"));
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
        source.OnNext(new Pair("A", "at"));
        source.OnNext(new Pair("B", "empty"));
        source.OnNext(new Pair("A", "empty"));
        source.OnNext(new Pair("C", "new"));

        Console.ReadLine();
```