# Conditional delay+throttle operator

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I'm writing a custom RX operator that combines features from both Throttle and Delay, with the following signature

```
public static IObservable<T> DelayWhen(this IObservable<T> self, TimeSpan delay, Func<T, bool> condition);
```

The rules are as follows:

1. If `condition(t)` returns `false`, emit immediately.
2. If `condition(t)` returns `true`, delay for  `delay` time.
3. If `self` emits a value during a delay then do the following:

   1. If `condition(t)` returns `false`, cancel/skip the value scheduled for delayed emission and emit the new value
   2. If `condition(t)` returns `true` then skip/ignore this new value (i.e. the delayed value will emit if `self` does not emit any more values during the delay).

As you can tell from the rules, there is some behavior reminiscent of throttling going on here.

My various attempts at solving this issue include some `async` approaches that just grew to complex. I really feel this should be solvable using existing operators. E.g. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/16290788/2149075, which uses `Amb` quite neatly and which I feel is really close to what I want to achieve.

Comment: What should happen in case more than one delayed values are followed by a non-delayed value? Should all currently delayed (scheduled) values be discarded?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Fair comment. The condition should obviously be the other way. I will update. Regarding your second comment: any value coming in that should be delayed is to be ignored. It does not “replace” the currently delayed value (Unless, of course, condition 3.1. occurs).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question isn't completely clear, so using the following test case as a scenario:

```
Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
    .Take(10)
    .DelayWhen(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.5), i => i % 3 == 0 || i % 2 == 0)
```

This should result in the following:

```
//        T: ---1---2---3---4---5---6---7---8---9---0---1----
// original: ---0---1---2---3---4---5---6---7---8---9
//   delay?: ---Y---N---Y---Y---Y---N---Y---N---Y---Y
// expected: -------1---------2-----5-------7-------------8
//
// 0: Delayed, but interrupted by 1, 
// 1: Non-delayed, emit immediately
// 2: Delayed, emit after 1.5 seconds
// 3: Delayed, since emitted during a delay, ignored
// 4: Delayed, but interrupted by 5.
// 5: Non-delayed, emit immediately
// 6: Delayed, but interrupted by 7.
// 7: Non-delayed, emit immediately
// 8: Delayed, but interrupted by 9
// 9: Delayed, since emitted during a delay, ignored
```

If that doesn't line up with the requirements, please clarify the question. @Theodore's solution gets the timing right, but emits 3 and 9, ignoring the "cancel/skip the value scheduled for delayed emission and emit the new value" clause.

This is functionally equivalent to Theodore's code, but (IMO) easier to work with and understand:

```
public static IObservable<T> DelayWhen2<T>(this IObservable<T> source, TimeSpan delay, Func<T, bool> condition, IScheduler scheduler)
{
    return source
        .Select(x => (Item: x, WithDelay: condition(x)))
        .Publish(published => published
            .SelectMany(t => t.WithDelay 
                ? Observable.Return(t)
                    .Delay(delay, scheduler)
                    .TakeUntil(published.Where(t2 => !t2.WithDelay))
                : Observable.Return(t)
            )
        )
        .Select(e => e.Item);
}
```

From there, I had to embed the state of whether or not you're in delay with `.Scan`:

```
public static IObservable<T> DelayWhen3<T>(this IObservable<T> source, TimeSpan delay, Func<T, bool> condition)
{
    return DelayWhen3(source, delay, condition, Scheduler.Default);
}

public static IObservable<T> DelayWhen3<T>(this IObservable<T> source, TimeSpan delay, Func<T, bool> condition, IScheduler scheduler)
{
    return source
        .Select(x => (Item: x, WithDelay: condition(x)))
        .Publish(published => published
            .Timestamp(scheduler)
            .Scan((delayOverTime: DateTimeOffset.MinValue, output: Observable.Empty<T>()), (state, t) => {
                if(!t.Value.WithDelay)  
                    //value isn't delayed, current delay status irrelevant, emit immediately, and cancel previous delay.
                    return (DateTimeOffset.MinValue, Observable.Return(t.Value.Item));
                else
                    if (state.delayOverTime > t.Timestamp)
                        //value should be delayed, but current delay already in progress. Ignore value.
                        return (state.delayOverTime, Observable.Empty<T>());
                    else
                        //value should be delayed, no delay in progress. Set delay state, and return delayed observable.
                        return (t.Timestamp + delay, Observable.Return(t.Value.Item).Delay(delay, scheduler).TakeUntil(published.Where(t2 => !t2.WithDelay)));
            })
        )
        .SelectMany(t => t.output);
}
```

In the `.Scan` operator, you embed the time when the previous `Delay` expires. That way you know can handle a value that should be delayed within an existing delay. I added `scheduler` parameters to the time-sensitive functions to enable testing:

```
var ts = new TestScheduler();

var target = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), ts)
    .Take(10)
    .DelayWhen3(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.5), i => i % 3 == 0 || i % 2 == 0, ts);

var observer = ts.CreateObserver<long>();
target.Subscribe(observer);
ts.Start();

var expected = new List<Recorded<Notification<long>>> {
    new Recorded<Notification<long>>(2000.MsTicks(), Notification.CreateOnNext<long>(1)),
    new Recorded<Notification<long>>(4500.MsTicks(), Notification.CreateOnNext<long>(2)),
    new Recorded<Notification<long>>(6000.MsTicks(), Notification.CreateOnNext<long>(5)),
    new Recorded<Notification<long>>(8000.MsTicks(), Notification.CreateOnNext<long>(7)),
    new Recorded<Notification<long>>(10500.MsTicks(), Notification.CreateOnNext<long>(8)),
    new Recorded<Notification<long>>(10500.MsTicks() + 1, Notification.CreateOnCompleted<long>()),
};

ReactiveAssert.AreElementsEqual(expected, observer.Messages);
```

And code for MsTicks:

```
public static long MsTicks(this int i)
{
    return TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(i).Ticks;
}
```

Comment: You're marble diagram is exactly right. I should probably have provided one myself. Lesson learned. Looking at your code now :)

Comment: One question right off the bat - in `TakeUntil` you're reusing the published `IObservable`. Everything is on the same thread here, so race conditions isn't really a concern but still - when the `TakeUntil` is evaluated, will it be evaluated with the same value as was just emitted from `published`? That seems like the logical behavior but I'm curious about what guarantees the order here. What is preventing what's inside the `TakeUntil` to happen after `TakeUntil` is evaluated?

Comment: In this case, they are reverse sides of the boolean: You only produce the chain when `.WithDelay` and the produced chain checks when not `.WithDelay`. But even without that, the Observable produces the Delay/TakeUntil chain won't consume the element that causes it to be produced. Then you have circles

Answer (score 2):

Here is an implementation of the `DelayWhen` operator, that is based on the built-in [`Window`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/window.html) operator:

---

**Update:** My original implementation ([Revision 1](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/67363561/1)) did not satisfy the requirements of the question, so I changed it by replacing the `Delay` operator with a custom-made delaying/throttling operator.

```
/// <summary>
/// Either delays the emission of the elements that satisfy the condition, by the
/// specified time duration, or ignores them, in case they are produced before
/// the emission of previously delayed element. Elements that don't satisfy the
/// condition are emitted immediately, and they also cancel any pending emission of
/// all previously delayed elements.
/// </summary>
public static IObservable<T> DelayWhen<T>(this IObservable<T> source,
    TimeSpan delay, Func<T, bool> condition, IScheduler scheduler = null)
{
    // Arguments validation omitted
    scheduler ??= DefaultScheduler.Instance;
    return source
        .Select(x => (Item: x, WithDelay: condition(x)))
        .Publish(published => published.Window(published.Where(e => !e.WithDelay)))
        .Select(w => Observable.Merge(
            DelayThrottleSpecial(w.Where(e => e.WithDelay), delay, scheduler),
            w.Where(e => !e.WithDelay)
        ))
        .Switch()
        .Select(e => e.Item);

    /// <summary>
    /// Time shifts the observable sequence by the specified time duration, ignoring
    /// elements that are produced while a previous element is scheduled for emission.
    /// </summary>
    static IObservable<T2> DelayThrottleSpecial<T2>(IObservable<T2> source,
        TimeSpan dueTime, IScheduler scheduler)
    {
        int mutex = 0; // 0: not acquired, 1: acquired
        return source.SelectMany(x =>
        {
            if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref mutex, 1, 0) == 0)
                return Observable.Return(x)
                    .DelaySubscription(dueTime, scheduler)
                    .Finally(() => Volatile.Write(ref mutex, 0));
            return Observable.Empty<T2>();
        });
    }
}
```

The source sequence is partitioned in consecutive windows (subsequences), with each window ending with a `false` (non delayed) element. Each window is then projected to a new window that has its `true` (delayed) elements delayed/throttled according to the requirements. Finally the projected windows are merged back to a single sequence by using the [`Switch`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/switch.html) operator, so that all pending elements of a window are discarded every time a new window is emitted.

Comment: Thanks:) Looks like a neat solution, but one question. When a window is projected into the Merge, all the delayed items are in fact delayed. Let's assume they are delayed long enough for a non-delayed value to emit from the window. In a marble diagram (x delayed; o not delayed) we get x-x-x-o gets shitfted to o-x-x-x. However, how are the delayed items prevented from being emitted? Would that not require a new window to appear so the Switch can do it's work?

Comment: @AlexanderHøst the `Window` overload that is used in my answer produces windows that touch to each other: closing a window results to the immediate opening of the next window. The new window is opened without waiting for the emission of the next value in the source sequence. The projected windows may overlap with each other, because of the time-shifting, as your marble diagram indicates, but then the `Switch` "truncates" the overlapping part of the previous window, because of the immediately following new window.

Comment: Aha - that clears it up for me. I was not aware that the next window is opened before a value is emitted but now that I think about it, that's really the only thing that makes sense given how Switch behaves. I'm writing a couple of unit tests, but this really seems like the right way to go :)

Comment: @AlexanderHøst yeap, it seems to behave correctly according to my own tests, but it does require a leap of faith regarding how the `Window` operator behaves. What happens when the windowed sequence and the boundaries-producing sequence is the same sequence (or derived from each other)? It seems that the boundary element becomes the last element of the closing window, and not the first element of the opening window, and this behavior is consistent. But AFAICS it's not documented, and it could be easily implemented to be the other way around.

Comment: There's an error in this solution, see below.

Comment: @Shlomo yeap, you are right. I should have spent more time reading the requirements for the requested operator. 

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Ah, yes, that was the second thing I was wondering about. What gets evaluated first when you put `published.Where(e => !e.WithDelay)` inside the `Window()` operator. I guess I need a test for that.

Comment: @Shlomo Nice catch - looking at this as well now :)